# Find partition key of stateful service at runtime

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I need to find the current partition key of a Service Fabric Stateful Service at run time.

I have looked in the `ICodePackageActivationContext` and the `StatefulServiceContext` but can't seem to see this information anywhere.

**Edit:**

As [LoekD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5946937/loekd) pointed out in his answer this information is available from within the `StatefulService` class. Just to be explicitly clear, here is how I accessed:

```
var info = (Int64RangePartitionInformation) this.Partition.PartitionInfo;

var highKey = info.HighKey;
var lowKey = info.LowKey;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within the service itself, you can use the `Partition.PartitionInfo` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.istatefulservicepartition?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: always happy to help